# ideal I=(x^3,x^5) of the polynomial ring Q[x]

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Given the ideal I=(x^3,x^5) of the polynomial ring Q[x]
1) 1 example of a polynomial which belongs to I and has 4 non-zero terms
2) 1 example of a polynomial which doesn't belong to I and has 3 non-zero terms.

I didn't really understand when a polynomial belongs to an ideal in this kind of a situation (x^3,x^5) 
An advice /explication would be enough and much appreciated.

Comment: A polynomial p belongs to I if it's a combination of the generators multiplied by some other polynomials of Q[x]. A trivial example is their sum but $x*x^3 + 3*x^5$ also belongs for example

Comment: Is not $I=(x^3)$?? Because $(x^5)\sunset (x^3)$

Comment: Lol yes totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

If by term you mean coefficient then $(1+x)*x^3 + (1+x)*x^5$ is an example for the first. $1+x+x^2$ is an example for the second question

Comment: thanks, i thought the teacher wanted terms(bcs in the problem is using the word terms) but maybe coefficients made more sense.

Comment: I am not sure the second example is correct ...             bcs  x^3(1/x^2-1/x)+x^5(1/x^3+1/x^5+1/x^3)=1+x+x^2